# How to restrict user for SQL Login only with New Password after changing password

Tags: sql, authentication

I am developing a WPF application with SQL Server 2014.

In our server side, I have created SQL Login as

```
CREATE LOGIN <username> WITH PASSWORD = <oldPassword> MUST_CHANGE,CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON,CHECK_POLICY=ON, DEFAULT_DATABASE =<databaseName> DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English]
```

Now after changing the password of above user by

```
ALTER LOGIN <username> WITH PASSWORD = <newPassword> , OLD_PASSWORD =<oldPassword> , DEFAULT_DATABASE=<databaseName>, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English]
```

I am able to open this connection with Old Password and new password both (by using  VS2013 C# connection string ). Condition : It will work only till we restart our server or service.

As per the requirement, user should be able to login only with new password. Can this community help me.

Do we have some restriction in SQL to open connection/login only with New Password.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your command when changing the password.

```
OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword'
```

I think you might just be adding another password rather than replacing it with your current command.

Comment: No, I am changing the password.